# PHP looping limit the number

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, limit

I have to submit all telephone numbers from my database records to URL, but I need to restrict each time send 300 phone numbers only.

I need a php script able to run following scenario:

1. Retrieve 2,000 records from database.
2. Loop all rows and save each into a variable or something else. (important)
3. Count total has 2,000 records.
4. Loop 300 records each time to write into URL. (very important)
5. Submit the URL (this part no need to explain)
6. loop for next 300 records to write into URL, and repeat it until record 2,000.

I believe in this case, 2,000 / 300 = 7 times of looping, which 300 records for first 6 times and final time is sending 200 records only.

As I mentioned above the looping for 300 records is very important, and next looping able to know starting from record 301 until 600, and so on.

**EDITED**

Below are my original code, but it's reading all phone numbers and dumb them all to my URL:

```
    $smsno = trim($_REQUEST['string_of_phone_number_eg_0123456;0124357;0198723']);
    $message = trim($_REQUEST['message']);

    $phoneNo = explode(";", $smsno);

    // ----------
    //
    // Need to count total $phoneNo, eg total is 2,000 phone numbers
    // Loop 300 times for the phone numbers, eg 001-300, 301-600, 401-900, ..., 1501-1800, 1801-2000
    // Every 300 records, eg $phoneStr =  '0123456;0124357;0198723;...' total 300 phone numbers in this string
    // Write into my URL:  $link = "http://smsexample.com/sms.php?destinationnumber=$phoneStr&messagetosms=$message";
    //
    // ----------
```

I am seeking solution from here as I have no idea how to loop each 300 records and write into string then throw this string to my URL.

I can make the first 300 records, but how to get next 300 records after first 300 records write into string and throw to my url, and waiting to perform second throw to url.

For example,

first loop for 300 records: 
$phoneStr = phoneNumber01;phoneNumber02;phoneNumber03;...;phoneNumber300
$link = "http://smsexample.com/sms.php?destinationnumber=$phoneStr&messagetosms=$message";

second loop for next 300 records
$phoneStr = phoneNumber301;phoneNumber302;phoneNumber303;...;phoneNumber600
$link = "http://smsexample.com/sms.php?destinationnumber=$phoneStr&messagetosms=$message";

and so on.

Comment: What have you got so far? Please update your post.

Comment: sounds like an order.... and we aren't your employee

Comment: @Jleagle , I have updated the code on my post.

Comment: @itachi , I feel you are not a professional user, or even thinking before commenting the post. I am seeking the solution from Q&A, and my questions was asking by me, if you are not understand, please do not simply comment such rudely like a caveman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Per-request limit
$limit = 300;

// Get array of numbers
$numbers = explode(';', $_REQUEST['string_of_phone_number_eg_0123456;0124357;0198723']);

// Get message
$message = trim($_REQUEST['message']);

// Loop numbers
while ($numbers) {

  // Get a block of numbers
  $thisBlock = array_splice($numbers, 0, $limit);

  // Build request URL
  $url = "http://smsexample.com/sms.php?destinationnumber=".urlencode(implode(';', $thisBlock))."&messagetosms=".urlencode($message);

  // Send the request
  $response = file_get_contents($url);

}
```

Comment: I have updated my post for the code written by me, please kindly advise me what to enhance from the code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 2000; $i++)
{
    if ($i % 300 == 0 || $i == 2000)
    {
        //Make URL and send
    }
}
```

Comment: @DaveRandom or you could just make your requests with `($i+1)` if it was necessary to start with 1.

Comment: @Jack , I have updated my post for the code written by me, please kindly advise me what to enhance from the code. thanks